# npm run build on windows 10 gives This app can't run on your PC

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, nvm, npm-scripts

Trying to run the command npm run build on my system but keep getting this
error. Tried uninstalling node but no luck. Any pointers would be helpful

[image]

Comment: So reinstall node.

Comment: ran as an admin..

Comment: @RahulGanguly Yep! I should've seen the screenshot closely. Try out following if it helps: 1. If node uninstalled -> reinstall 2. `npm cache verify` 3. `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Added nvm tag since my answer was all about nvm.

Comment: @emix it might help some. I'm as much a fan of nuking from orbit as anyone, but a little subtlety and understanding the issue did the trick for me this time around.

Answer (score 5):

The issue for me was that I am using nvm, and for reasons I don't yet know, when I try to set my node version to 12.14.0, and then run nvm list, no versions are selected. I went back to 13.8.0 and nvm list showed that 13.8.0 was selected.

Long story short, make sure you have a selected node version.

Answer (score 1):

I was also using nvm. My problem was that the version was not properly being used.

Normally when running `nvm list` there is an asterisk (*) next to the current in-use version. But that was not the case (even after running `nvm use x.x.x`)

I installed a second node version and uninstalled the first one and reinstalled it. After that I could switch and run npm install.

Comment: Right, I also had to install other versions. Switch between versions. Uninstall and Install the desired version again. Then finally I was able to see that * after running command - nvm use 14.15.1  and nvm list. Thank you so much @Gaetan vdb  for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

you should follow one of two option:

**Option 1 – Setup by running the .msi installation file**

- Its a typical Windows installation and automated.
- No need to add entries in environment varaiable

**Option 2 – Setup by extracting .zip file**

- This method does not require admin access and can be used to install on nodejs on a system on which you dont have admin access such as you official laptop or desktop.
- Removing nodejs is as simple as deleting the folder.
- You will have to add entries in environment variable if you want to execute node command from any location in windows command prompt.

See the link below for more details : [install Node.js and NPM on Windows 10](https://www.shaileshjha.com/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: I had a problem with a corrupt node js package downloaded by nvm. So I did the following to solve the problem:

1. Remove the broken node version in `%appdata%\nvm`
2. Download the "zip installer" from node.js homepage
3. Unzip the file and place the subfolder with the corresponding naming pattern in `%appdata%\nvm`

[image: rename generic to version number]

nvm is simply changing symbolic links to the correct node version. So make sure you have the same folder pattern and structure as for a working version and it works like charm.